Gaussian processes for Machine Learning, Rasmussen, Exercise 4.6
Problem
Show that the Squared Exponential Process (a Gaussian Process with the squared exponential kernel) is infinitely MS differentiable and that the OU process is not MS differentiable.
My attempt at solution
I believe if a process $f(x)$ is MS differentiable, then there must be a $f'(x)$ such that
$$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\mathbb{E}\left[ \left\vert\frac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{h} - f'(x) \right\vert ^2\right] = 0$$
for all $x$. However, I'm not sure where to go from here, expanding the term inside the absolute value may allow us to invoke properties of the covariance function but I don't know how to fix the value of $f'(x)$ to show that the expectation goes to 0. Any hints would be appreciated!

We say that a function $k : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ has property $\text{(P)}$ if it is an even covariance function which is analytic on $\mathbb{R}$. In particular, property $\text{(P)}$ implies:

$k(-x) = k(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$,
$k(x)$ is infinitely differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$, and
$k(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^{2n}$ for some sequence $(a_n)$, with positive radius of convergence.

Now that the squared exponential kernel $k(x) = \exp(-\frac{x^2}{2\ell^2})$ has property $\text{(P)}$. Now we claim:

Theorem. If $k(x)$ has property $\text{(P)}$, then the corresponding centered gaussian process $f(x)$ is MS differentiable. Moreover, the covariance kernel of $f'(x)$ is $-k''(x)$, which has property $\text{(P)}$.

This theorem automatically implies that $f(x)$ is infinitely MS differentiable.

Proof of Theorem. We first show that $f'(x)$ exists. Define
$$ g_\delta(x) = \frac{f(x+\delta) - f(x)}{\delta}. $$
Then for any non-zero $\delta$ and $\epsilon$, we have
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}\left[ \| g_\delta(x) - g_\epsilon(x) \|^2 \right]
&= \frac{2[k(0) - k(\delta)]}{\delta^2}
+ \frac{2[k(0) - k(\epsilon)]}{\epsilon^2} \\
&\quad - \frac{2[k(\epsilon - \delta) + k(0) - k(\epsilon) - k(\delta)]}{\epsilon\delta}.
\end{align*}
Assume in addition that $\delta$ and $\epsilon$ are sufficiently small so that it lies inside of the interval of convergence of the power series of $k(x)$ about $x = 0$. Then by expanding the terms using the power series, it is not hard to see that
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}\left[ \| g_\delta(x) - g_\epsilon(x) \|^2 \right]
&= [a_1 + \mathcal{O}(\delta^2)] + [a_1 + \mathcal{O}(\epsilon^2)] - 2[a_1 + \mathcal{O}(\delta\epsilon)] \\
&= \mathcal{O}(\min\{|\delta|,|\epsilon|\}^2).
\end{align*}
This shows that $g_\delta(x)$ is Cauchy as $\delta \to 0$. Since the $L^2$-space with respect to $\mathbb{P}$ is complete, it follows that $g_\delta(x)$ converges in mean square.
Let $f'(x)$ denote this limit. Being the limit of a centered gaussian process, $f'(x)$ is also a centered gaussian process. Moreover, its covariance kernel can be computed by noting that
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}\left[ f'(x)f'(y) \right]
&= \lim_{\delta \to 0} \mathbb{E}\left[ g_\delta(x)g_\delta(y) \right] \\
&= \lim_{\delta \to 0} \frac{2k(x-y) - k(x-y+\delta) - k(x-y-\delta)}{\delta^2}.
\end{align*}
The last limit can be computed by invoking the L'Hopital's rule twice, leading to
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}\left[ f'(x)f'(y) \right]
= -k''(x-y).
\end{align*}
This shows that $-k''(x)$ is a covariance function. It is also clear that $-f''(x)$ is even, infinitely differentiable, and analytic on $\mathbb{R}$. Hence $-k''(x)$ has property $\text{(P)}$. $\square$

For the second part, if $k(x)$ is the kernel of an OU process, then it is not hard to show that $\mathbf{Var}(g_\delta(x))$ diverges to $+\infty$ as $\delta \to 0$. I'll leave the details to OP.

Thank you so much for the clear and instructive solution!
